# Re rendering state after setting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to fetch data, and if I get an error while fetching. I want to wait 1000 seconds, and when fetch data again.

The problem is that in method settingTimeout() this.setState({timerStatus: true}); I'am expecting to rerender an entire application and render timeout in console.log. But for some reason it didn't do that. I tried using in settingTimeout() this.forceUpdate(); without much luck. [React similiar example](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class)

```
this.state = {
      retryTimer: 1000,
      timerStatus: false,
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    if(this.state.timerStatus){
      console.log('timeout');
    }
    this.newGame();
  }

  newGame =() => {
    Axios.get(
      this.state.apiBase + 'nexGame',
      this.state.headers
    )
    .then(response =>{
     console.log(response)
      }
    })
    .catch(error =>{
      this.settingTimeout();
    })
  }
  settingTimeout = () =>{
    this.setState({timerStatus: true});
    if(this.state.retryTimer === 0){
      this.newGame();
    }
  }
```

Comment: `this` might not be what you expect. Make `newGame` and `settingTimeout` into arrow functions and see if that works. `newGame = () => { ... }; settingTimeout = () => { ... };`

Comment: Where do you count down the retryTimer? you set a timeout but no interval is specified?

Comment: I didn't include set interval, because first I need to fix issue with printing console.log(timeout);

Comment: I think the reason why it is nog logged is because the setState hasn't finished yet as it's an async action, in a componentDidUpdate you should be able to see the result

Comment: Yes you right about that. Putting if statement in componentDidUpdate printed timeout

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want to make another call each 1s if the previous one failed, right ?

I'm not sure you need to re render you app to do that. If you want to remake this call you can use the react lifecycle with component https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating

with :

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if(this.nextState.timerStatus = true) { 
    setState({ timerStatus: false });
    this.newGame();
}
```

And put a timeout on your function settingTimeout when 1s is passed, change the state of timerStatus to true. React will watch this, put the timerStatus back to false and remake the call. If the call is okay you'll have your answer, if not you will wait 1s again and remake the call, etc etc.

Comment: I keep getting timerStatus is not defined are you sure timerStatus = false line is correct?

Comment: I believe that should be the timerStatus from the current state -> setState({ timerStatus: false })

Comment: yes of course it's setState as @ThibaultGobert stated it, i've replied too quickly

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following (explanation are under the fiddle):

```js
let counter = 0;

class App extends React.Component {
    timer;
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            data: "",
            loading: true,
            fetchError: false            
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        /* Simulating a fetch with setTimeout. */
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 100;
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            /* Here you would write .then(). */
            if (counter === 2) {
                this.setState({loading: false});
            }
            
            /* Here you would write .catch(). */
            if (counter === 0) {
                this.setState({fetchError: true});
                this.timer = setInterval(this.handleFetch, 1000);
            }
            
            counter++;
        }, random);
    }
    
    handleFetch = () => {
        /* Simulating a fetch with setTimeout. */
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 100;
        setTimeout(() => {
            /* This would be the then(), where you save the data. */
            if (counter === 2) {
                clearInterval(this.timer);
                this.setState({loading: false, fetchError: false, data: "YES!!"})
            }
            
            /* In this case, if the fetch fails, you do nothing. */
                                  
            counter++;
        }, random);
    }
    
    render() {
        const {fetchError, loading, data} =  this.state;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {loading && fetchError && <p>Error in Fetch</p>}
                {loading && !fetchError && <p>Loading</p>}
                {!loading && !fetchError && <p>{this.state.data}</p>}
           </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

First, I'm using `setTimeout` to simulate fetches. Furthermore, in order to simulate the fetch error, I'm using the `counter` variable: when it reaches the value `2`, then the fetch is considered correct, otherwise it's considered failed.
Said that, what's happening? In `componentDidMount` you run your first fetch: instead of `if (counter === 2)` you should write the `.then()` of your fetch (so, when it runs correctly). In that callback you can just set `this.state.loading` to `false`.
Otherwise, instead of `if (counter === 0)`, you should write the `catch()` statement: in that, you create the `interval` calling the `handleFetch()` function every `1000ms`. Notice that, in this case, you set `this.state.fetchError` to `true`: this way you can give better feedback to the user.

Now, inside the `handleFetch()` you perform the fetch: again, if it ends correctly, you can set `this.state.loading` and `this.state.fetchError` to `false`, and save the data in the state. 
Otherwise you just wait another `1000ms` for the next fetch.